# java paint function doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i am using java to draw ovals and connect them by lines , when i scan variables the paint function doesn't work at all

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main (){
        setTitle("Graph");
        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public   void paint (Graphics g,int x,int z,int y) {
        g.fillOval(x, x+20, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(x+10, x+50,x+z+10, z+30);
        g.fillOval(x+z, z, 40, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int z =scan.nextInt();
        int y =scan.nextInt();

        x=x+1;
        z=z+1;
        y=y+1; 

        Main m=new Main();
        Graphics g=m.getGraphics();
        m.paint(g, x, z, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: next time please take some time to choose an adequate title and proper code formatting.

Comment: okay i will , this is my first time

Comment: How does it not work? What does it do? Why are you showing us so much code? Only give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This my first time sorry , if you know how i can make it work please tell me

Comment: "okay i will , this is my first time , " You are welcome! Next time please read MCVE as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Override the JFrame s' paint method. Unless you do that it will not paint to the frame, Read this,
[Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Here is a Demonstration

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    public Main(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        setTitle("Graph");

        setSize(1000, 1000);

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.fillOval(x, x + 20, 40, 40);

        g.drawLine(x + 10, x + 50, x + z + 10, z + 30);

        g.fillOval(x + z, z, 40, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int z = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        x = x + 1;
        z = z + 1;
        y = y + 1;
        Main m = new Main(x, y, z);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics g=m.getGraphics();` is NOT how custom painting is done in Swing, apart from been able to returning `null`, it is simply a "snap shot" of what was last painted and could be painted over at any time

`public   void paint (Graphics g,int x,int z,int y) {` is not a method which is called during the paint process.  Java doesn't magically know that this method could be used for painting, you need to tell it.

Also, you shouldn't be mixing console based input with GUIs, pick one or the other...

Start by taking a look at

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

for more details about how painting works in Swing.

You should avoid painting directly to top level containers like `JFrame`, apart from the fact that you are not actually adding any new functionality to the frame, they (top level containers) are not double buffered and can cause flicker during updates and `JFrame` (and `JWindow` and `JApplet`) have `JRootPane` and a content pane (and sometimes a glass pane) between the frame and the user, this could cause any number of painting issues.

A better solution is to create a custom component based on something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` (making sure to call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting)

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main101();
    }

    public Main101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int x = 10;
        private int z = 10;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.fillOval(x, x + 20, 40, 40);

            g2d.drawLine(x + 10, x + 50, x + z + 10, z + 30);

            g2d.fillOval(x + z, z, 40, 40);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```